# AWS Cloudwatch Log filtered params available on Alarm notification

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using Cloudwatch and Lambda to monitor logs.
I have setup some filters that are triggered when a specific kind of error appears in the log.
Is it possible to send on the Cloudwatch Alarm SNS the params that are filtered on the Log?

For example:

**Receive Error :**

> [2017-06-29 17:58:52] prod.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined variable:
>   message X

**Metric Filter :**

> [date,info="*.ERROR:",error]

**Alarm :**

> IS OK when <= 0

Notification sent to SNS and Lambda to trigger different notification agents.

The SNS Event gives me this message , but I would like to access the filtered vars:

```
{
    "AlarmName": "PHP_ERROR",
    "AlarmDescription": null,
    "AWSAccountId": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "NewStateValue": "OK",
    "NewStateReason": "Threshold Crossed: no datapoints were received for 1 period and 1 missing datapoint was treated as [NonBreaching]",
    "StateChangeTime": "2017-06-29T17:09:12.336+0000",
    "Region": "EU - Ireland",
    "OldStateValue": "ALARM",
    "Trigger": {
        "MetricName": "PHP_ERROR",
        "Namespace": "Logs",
        "StatisticType": "Statistic",
        "Statistic": "SUM",
        "Unit": null,
        "Dimensions": [],
        "Period": 60,
        "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
        "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
        "Threshold": 0,
        "TreatMissingData": "- TreatMissingData:                    NonBreaching",
        "EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile": ""
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `alarm` is only looking at a `metric` to evaluate the threshold. So the short answer is **no** :(

Then, you have another level of abstraction, since the `metric` already is set from a particular value of the `filter`.

The [`filter`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) is the only place where you can find the extracted values, but it will only translate a match into a value or increment for a metric (ie: number), it will not work as a parsed log storage.

AWS recently released [*Cloudwatch Log Insights*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html) which may help you find the error messages.

Otherwise you can try the AWS [CLI filter for logs command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/filter-log-events.html), which allows you to browse logs.

#### Example in Ubuntu

```
export YOUR_LOG_GROUP_NAME=SomeLogGroup

# The 1000 multiplication is to convert from seconds to milliseconds
# If you already have a specific timestamp, just replace it on the start-time argument
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name $YOUR_LOG_GROUP_NAME \
--start-time $(($(date +%s --date="1 minute ago") * 1000)) \
--interleaved --filter-pattern ".ERROR" \
--output=text --query events[*].[message]
```

#### Example in OSx

```
export YOUR_LOG_GROUP_NAME=SomeLogGroup

# The 1000 multiplication is to convert from seconds to milliseconds
# If you already have a specific timestamp, just replace it on the start-time argument
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name $YOUR_LOG_GROUP_NAME \
--start-time $(($(date -v-1M +%s) * 1000)) \
--interleaved --filter-pattern ".ERROR" \
--output=text --query events[*].[message]
```

If you want to automate it, you can replace the trigger action, to call a lambda (using some AWS SDK instead of the CLI) that would be able to generate the desired message for SNS with this information.

ie:

- From: `Metric -> Alarm -> SNS`
- To: `Metric -> Alarm -> Lambda -> SNS`